# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, json, postman

estoy teniendo el siguiente error:

`Notice: Trying to get property 'idDia' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\backend-trabajo-final\profesionales\select-profesionales-para-posible-servicio.php on line 26` (Así, con cada una de las propiedades que intento extraer de la variable $obj que está en el .php) y por último me captura una excepcion:

```
Excepción capturada: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

Estoy usando Postman para hacer las prueba, utilizo el método POST y en el Body utilizo raw con el tipo JSON(application/json) y le mando los siguientes datos:

```
{
    "idDia" : 4,
    "fecha" : '2018-09-20',
    "hora" : '09:00:00',
    "idOficio" : 1,
    "idArea" : 1
}
```

El archivo .php es éste:

```
<?php

    //DEFINE LOS PARAMETROS DE CONEXION
    $host = 'localhost';
    $usuarioBD = 'root';
    $passBD = '';
    $bd = 'tf';
    $codif = 'utf8';

    //CONFIGURA LOS PARAMETROS
    $url = "mysql:host=" . $host . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $bd . ";charset=" . $codif;
    $opt = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                );

    //CREA LA INSTANCIA DE PDO (CONECTA A LA BD)
    $pdo = new PDO($url, $usuarioBD, $passBD, $opt);

    //RECIBE LOS DATOS DEL FRONTEND EN FORMATO JSON
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //LOS DECODIFICA
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    //EXTRAE LOS DATOS RECIBIDOS y ACÁ ABAJO DONDE ME TIRA EL ERROR
    $idDia = $obj->idDia;
    $fecha = $obj->fecha;
    $hora = $obj->hora;
    $idOficio = $obj->idOficio; 
    $idArea = $obj->idArea;

    var_dump($json);
    var_dump($obj);

    try {

        //BUSCA LOS PROFESIONALES QUE NO PUEDEN
        $sql1 = "SELECT profesionales.idProfesional, usuarios.idUsuario, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.apellido from profesionales, usuarios,
    (select T.idProfesional, servicios.hora
    from  detallesservicios inner join servicios 
    on detallesservicios.idServicio = servicios.idServicio inner join (select profesionales.idProfesional from horarios, profesionales where
    horarios.idDia = :idDia
    and profesionales.idEstadoP = 1
    and horarios.desde < :hora_i
    and horarios.hasta > :hora_j
    and horarios.idArea = :idArea
    and profesionales.idOficio = :idOficio
    group by profesionales.idProfesional) as T on
    T.idProfesional = detallesservicios.idProfesional
    where servicios.fecha = :fecha and not(timediff(servicios.hora, :hora_k) > '00:57:00')
    group by servicios.idServicio order by T.idProfesional) as TT
    where profesionales.idProfesional <> TT.idProfesional
    and profesionales.idUsuario = usuarios.idUsuario
    group by profesionales.idProfesional";
        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':idOficio', $idOficio);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':hora_i', $hora);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':hora_j', $hora);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':hora_k', $hora);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':idDia', $idDia);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':idArea', $idArea);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $filasDevuelta = $stmt1->rowCount();

        //SI LO ENCUENTRA, SINO
        if(($filasDevuelta) > (0)) {

            while($fila  = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
                // Asigna cada fila de datos a la matriz asociativa
                $datosNoUsuarios[] = $fila;
            }

            // Devuelve los datos como JSON
            console.log("Datos noUsuarios: " . $datosNoUsuarios);
            echo json_encode($datosNoUsuarios);

        } else {

            //echo 'No existe el usuario.';
            echo '{"error":{"texto":"No existen profesionales para el servicio solicitado."}}';

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo 'Excepción capturada: '.  $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Como pueden ver, `$obj` toma el valor decodificado de la entrada `$json`, pero no puedo mas abajo extraer los datos con las propiedades (por ejemplo: `$idDia = $obj->idDia`) y así con todas las otras propiedades de `$obj`.

En los `var_dump()` me vienen los siguientes valores:

```
C:\para-posible-servicio.php:32:string '{   "idDia" : 4,
    "fecha" : '2018-09-20',
    "hora" : '09:00:00',
    "idOficio" : 1,
    "idArea" : 1 }' (length=94)
C:\para-posible-servicio.php:33:null
```

Es decir, en el `$json` vienen datos, pero no los toma `$obj`.

Lo raro es que el código lo copie de otros archivos que hice y que funcionan bien.
Puede ser que le mande mal los datos JSON pero los comprobé varias veces y no hay caso.

Comment: El problema es que tu json no es válido, no se admiten valores con comillas simples como estos: `"fecha" : '2018-09-20',
    "hora" : '09:00:00',`, debes corregir eso donde se origina tu json, si pruebas con esto debería funcionar: **`$json='{
    "idDia" : 4,
    "fecha" : "2018-09-20",
    "hora" : "09:00:00",
    "idOficio" : 1,
    "idArea" : 1
}';
    $obj = json_decode($json); //resto del código`**  nótese que en las claves `fecha` y `hora` se ponen los valores usando comillas dobles `"`.

Comment: ¡Gracias @A.Cedano ! Eso ha sido la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que **tu json no es válido**, no se admiten valores con comillas simples como estos:

```
"fecha" : '2018-09-20', 
"hora" : '09:00:00',
```

por lo que [este json no valida](https://jsonlint.com):

```
{
    "idDia" : 4,
    "fecha" : '2018-09-20',
    "hora" : '09:00:00',
    "idOficio" : 1,
    "idArea" : 1
}
```

> Error: Parse error on line 3: ...dDia": 4,    "fecha":
>   '2018-09-20', "hora
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Debes por tanto generar un [json válido](https://jsonlint.com):

```
{
    "idDia": 4,
    "fecha": "2018-09-20",
    "hora": "09:00:00",
    "idOficio": 1,
    "idArea": 1
}
```

> Valid JSON

Nótese que en las claves fecha y hora se ponen los valores usando comillas dobles `"`.

A partir de ahí, el resto del código debería funcionar.